# Hibernate XML - composite-id with one-to-one mapping

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I cannot get it to work. The error says `Broken column mapping`. It has to be one-sided one-to-one mapping. Only 1 part of composite-id is connected to the other entity. Channel gonna be inserted based on logged user's access channel. I do have 2 classes.

```
public class UserModel implements Serializable{
    private final Long id;
    private final UserLimitsModel userLimitsModel;

}
```

```
public class UserLimitsModel implements Serializable{
    private final Long userId;    
    private final String channel;
}
```

Then 2 hibernate .xml mappings

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="abcdefgh.UserLimitsModel" table="USER_LIMITS" lazy="false">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="userId" type="long">
                <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true"/>
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="channel" type="string" length="20">
                <column name="CHANNEL" not-null="true"/>
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="abcdefgh.UserModel" table="USER" lazy="false">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" precision="19" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence_name">ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="userLimitsModel" class="abcdefgh.UserLimitsModel" cascade="all"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So the only connection is `UserModel.id` = `UserLimitsModel.userId`, while channel stays separate.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem is that you are not joining with the primary key. Also the column name in UserModel is ID and in UserLimitsModel is USER_ID. You need to tell hibernate how to perform the join
 you can do this by defining property-ref on the one-to-one element.

```
<one-to-one name="userLimitsModel" class="abcdefgh.UserLimitsModel" property-ref="userId" cascade="all"/>
```

> property-ref (optional): the name of a property of the associated
>   class that is joined to the primary key of this class. If not
>   specified, the primary key of the associated class is used.

Comment: `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property [userId] not found on entity [abcdefgh.UserLimitsModel]"}}`

Comment: Does the column name matter? I want it to be ID in UserModel and USER_ID in UserLimitsModel. I still cannot find way to join both tables. :(

Comment: Can yluo try defining getter and setter for the field?